# Renumbering numbers in a text file based on an unique mapping

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I have a big txt file with 2 columns and more than 2 million rows. Every value represents an id and there may be duplicates. There are about 100k unique ids.

```
1342342345345 34523453452343
0209239498238 29349203492342
2349234023443 99203900992344
2349234023443 182834349348
2923000444 9902342349234
```

I want to identify each id and re-number all of them starting from 1. It should re-number duplicates also using the same new id. If possible, it should be done using bash.

The output could be something like:

```
123 485934
34 44834
167 34564
167 2345
2 34564
```

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: Why is there no "1" in your example?

Comment: because the file do not start with the lowest id value. Briefly, my file is not ordered by default

Comment: So "21 13 21 987 55" should become "2 1 2 4 3", is that right?

Comment: Is there a requirement that the lowest id value becomes "1", the 2nd lowest "2", etc?

Comment: @Beta yes, that's the idea

Comment: @glennjackman no, just start with 1 for the sake of simplicity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doing this in pure bash will be really slow. I'd recommend:

```
tr -s '[:blank:]' '\n' <file |
  sort -un |
  awk '
    NR == FNR {id[$1] = FNR; next}
    {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {$i = id[$i]}; print}
  ' - file
```

```
4 8
3 7
5 9
5 2
1 6
```

Answer (score 4):

With bash and sort:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s lastpipe
declare -A hash    # declare associative array
index=1

# read file and fill associative array
while read -r a b; do
  echo "$a"
  echo "$b"
done <file | sort -nu | while read -r x; do
  hash[$x]="$((index++))"
done

# read file and print values from associative array
while read -r a b; do
  echo "${hash[$a]} ${hash[$b]}"
done < file
```

Output:

```
4 8
3 7
5 9
5 2
1 6
```

---

See: `man bash` and `man sort`

Answer (score 1):

Pure Bash, with a single read of the file:

```
declare -A hash
index=1
while read -r a b; do
  [[ ${hash[$a]} ]] || hash[$a]=$((index++))   # assign index only if not set already
  [[ ${hash[$b]} ]] || hash[$b]=$((index++))   # assign index only if not set already
  printf '%s %s\n' "${hash[$a]}" "${hash[$b]}"
done < file > file.indexed
```

Notes:

- the index is assigned in the order read (not based on sorting)
- we make a single pass through the file (not two as in other solutions)
- Bash's read is slower than awk; however, if the same logic is implemented in Perl or Python, it will be much faster
- this solution is more CPU bound because of the hash lookups

Output:

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
5 7
8 9
```

Comment: thank you, but your solution is not correct and is by far the slowest one.

Comment: Yes, bash `read` will be slow if the files are large.  I added my answer since you wanted a bash solution.

Comment: @paketecuento: please let me know what is wrong here.

Comment: This being the slowest says a lot about sticking to just the shell, rather than using another tool. +1 for sticking to that bit of the brief.

Comment: @codeforester: the output file size of your proposal differs from the correct solution. Based on this, I conclude your solution is not correct. Sorry, but I can not state clearly where maybe you're wrong :(. In any case, thank your for you approach

Comment: @paketecuento: the output file size could be different because the indices are assigned in a serial fashion, in the same order as how IDs appear in input file.  The accepted answer does a unique sort of the file while assigning the indexes and hence the output can differ.  However, my solution gives you the output exactly as stated in your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'NR==FNR { ids[$1] = ++c; next }
{ print ids[$1], ids[$2] }
' <( { cut -d' ' -f1 renum.in; cut -d' ' -f2 renum.in; } | sort -nu ) renum.in
```

join the two columns into one then `sort` the that into numerical order (`-n`), and make unique (`-u`), before using `awk` to use this sequence to generate an array of mappings between old to new `ids`.

Then for each line in input, swap `ids` and print.

Comment: The question says "Every value represent [an] id", even those in 2nd column.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep a monotonic counter and a table of seen numbers; when you see a new id, give it the value of the counter and increment:

```
awk '!a[$1]{a[$1]=++N} {$1=a[$1]} !a[$2]{a[$2]=++N} {$2=a[$2]} 1' input
```